# Is it possible to print cucumber feature file steps to Jenkins? console while execution is in progress?

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, jenkins-plugins

Is it possible to print cucumber feature file steps to Jenkins console while execution is in progress?

Please let me know if more info is required.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, afaik this is default behaviour. (We run Cucumber tests on Jenkins and I can follow the progress via the "Console log").

You might need to specify the plugin to use for reporting. If you are using a runner class, you can do so as follows:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"json:yourproject-test/target/cucumber.json", "pretty"}
)
public class RunCucumberTest {
}
```

For more on built-in plugins, see the [docs on reporter plugins](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/reporting/#built-in-reporter-plugins)

Comment: thanks @Marit. Actually also i want to know about how to print steps in console

Comment: How are you running cucumber? I think you might need to specify the reporter plugin.

Comment: @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = { "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:Cucumber-Reports/Cucumber-Report.html","rerun:Failed_Scenario_Report/rerun.txt","pretty" }, 
 monochrome = true, 
 features = { "src/test/java/Features" }, 
 tags = {"@Regression" }, 
 glue = { "stepDefinitions" }, 
 dryRun = false, 
 strict = true) this is my cucmber class

Comment: Hmm, I'm not familiar with that plugin. Try the ones I mentioned?

Comment: yes I have used "Pretty" plugin but it displayed steps at the end of execution. I want to print steps (step by step)

Comment: Which version of Cucumber are you using? And are you running in parallel? Iirc Cucumber no longer outputs results during the run as of a certain version (3 or 4) / when running in parallel

Comment: I am using 1.2.5 version and not running in parallel.

Comment: v1.2.5 is very old. You might want to upgrade. Also, afaik this really should work (it does for me) so I'm not sure where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that.

1. Go to your Jenkins project
2. Select the item from the Build history
3. Select Console output

And you will get whatever your code outputs, including feature file steps.

Comment: thanks @Mate Mrse. Actually also i want to know about how to print steps in console. Sorry for i was not clear

Comment: @Mate It is not getting printed, How to print the feature name, scenario name, step name in jenkins console output. I use protractor cucumber and declared the cucumber options format properly

Comment: Have you followed the above steps?